# Firefox won't open links with flatpak or snap application

Tags: firefox, snap, flatpak, kde-neon

Firefox that was installed by default doesn't open links with snap or flatpak applications installed on my system. As an example, I am trying to log in to Todoist application installed locally on my computer. It only gives me the option to log in using a web browser(firefox). When firefox opens up I log in and the next window has a propt that says "Allow this app to open the com.todoist link with Todoist?". When I clicked the allow button nothing happens. I do not get logged in on the local app. It also happens with other apps (ex. Unity Hub and qBittorrent magnet links). The apps also doesn't give me another way to log in so I can't use the app at all. When I use transmission installed using the `apt install` command I can open magnet links but with qBitorrent Iinstalled using flatpak I have the same issue. Is there a workaround to this or do I really have to uninstall my snap or flatpak apps in order for it to work with firefox. I am running KDE Neon 5.27.